# Event handling for multiple pages printing

Tags: c#, winforms

The text document have more pages. They need to handle events for print more pages. But my code written for **Copy From Screen()** method.

**code :**

```
    public partial class print : Form 
    {   
        private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp, 0, 0);
        }  
        private void printbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            printDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = new System.Drawing.Printing.PaperSize("210 X 297", 820, 800);
            printPreviewDialog1.Document = printDocument1;

        Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();
        bmp = new Bitmap(this.Size.Width, this.Size.Height, g);
        Graphics g1 = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);   
        g1.CopyFromScreen(this.Location.X, this.Location.Y, 0, 0, this.Size);
        printPreviewDialog1.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

Comment: The `PrintPageEvents` object has a property `HasMorePages` which will tell the system if there’s more pages. Set it to true and the method will be called again until it’s false. Then just handle drawing each page in order

Comment: is need to create any extra forms for extra pages ?

Comment: No, just handle the event

Comment: It doesn't work to me : ( I don't have any pages I'm only have forms. That's why  it doesn't work to me.  I can't  share my screenshots else I'll show my forms. What I really mean then you can under stand.

Comment: please can you share your mail ID or whatsapp number to me ?

Comment: Printing is not so much different from painting onto a control. Your code shows that you don't really know about that either, I'm afraid. For proper quality you should use the PrintPage event to do all the drawing (or in a function to which you pass is e.Graphics object.) - The greatest difference is that the event must be able to keep track of which page it is printing, ie there must the a page counter etc declared outside of it at class level and it must set of clear the `hasmorepage` flag. (It also should keep track of the line/y-position on each page). There are many examples around!

Comment: is need any HTML code to create a page in winforms ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's up to you to break your pages up into pages and to keep track of what has been printed and whether there are more pages to print. Here is a simple example that will print an arbitrary list of text with ten lines to a page. It will keep printing pages with ten lines until there are no more lines to print.

```cs
private List<string> lines = new();
private int lineIndex;

private void printDocument1_BeginPrint(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintEventArgs e)
{
    lineIndex = 0;
}

private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < 10 && lineIndex < lines.Count; i++, lineIndex++)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawString(lines[lineIndex], Font, Brushes.Black, 0, i * 15);
    }

    e.HasMorePages = lineIndex < lines.Count;
}
```

The code resets the line index to zero at the start of each print run. It then prints up to ten lines on the current page and then prints another page if and only if there are still lines to print. It's a simple principle and you need to implement it in the appropriate way for your data.

Another variation is to use the `BeginPrint` event to process the data and break it into pages there, then print one of those pages per `PrintPage` event, e.g.

```cs
// All the lines to be printed.
private List<string> lines = new();

// The groups of lines to be printed on each page.
private List<string[]> pages;

// The index of the page being printed.
private int pageIndex;

private void printDocument1_BeginPrint(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintEventArgs e)
{
    // Print 10 lines per page.
    const int pageLineCount = 10;

    pages = new List<string[]>();

    // Take groups of up to 10 lines from the line liust and add them to the page list.
    for (var pageStartLineIndex = 0; pageStartLineIndex < lines.Count; pageStartLineIndex += pageLineCount)
    {
        pages.Add(lines.Skip(pageStartLineIndex).Take(pageLineCount).ToArray());
    }

    // Start printing at the first page.
    pageIndex = 0;
}

private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    // Get the current page and increment the page index.
    var page = pages[pageIndex++];

    // Print the current page.
    for (var i = 0; i < page.Length; i++)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawString(page[i], Font, Brushes.Black, 0, i * 15);
    }

    // Continue printing if and only if there are more pages to print.
    e.HasMorePages = pageIndex < pages.Count;
}
```